# [scala]How to make the BigDecimal is exact to integer part?

Tags: scala, biginteger, bigdecimal

On scala my BigDecimal is 3.721443204405954385563870541379242E+54
I would like to result to 3721443204405954385563870541379246659709506697378694300

My result is:
3.114968783111033211375362915188093E+41
I would like to result to be:
311496878311103321137536291518809134027240

I do not know the scale and the result should be only show the integer part.

```
val multimes:(Int, Int)=>BigDecimal=(c:Int, begin:Int)=>{
if(c==1)
  BigDecimal.apply(begin)
else
  multimes(c-1, begin)*(c+begin-1)
}

def mulCount(c:Int):BigDecimal={
val upper=multimes(c,c+1)
val down=multimes(c,2)
upper/down
}
```

the number is the result of function mulCount.

Comment: I am confused. Could you provide the source code? You're saying that your result is 3.11..., but that doesn't look like an integer.

Comment: @RadoBuransky I added source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BigDecimal` class has a number of nonintuitive behaviors in Scala 2.10.  This will get better in 2.11, but I can't quite tell from your example whether it will fix what you want.  Probably not; Scala has a default `MathContext` which keeps about 128 bits of information (~34 decimal digits), and I think that's what you're running into here.

If you don't have a decimal problem--and here you don't--then the easiest thing to do is just use `BigInt` instead.  It will scale to however many digits you actually need.

If you must express this as a decimal problem, you should explicitly supply a `MathContext` that has enough digits:

```
if (c==1) BigDecimal.apply(begin, new java.math.MathContext(60))
```

and that `MathContext` will, if always used on the left-hand side of operations, propagate through to your result.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though you're mostly concerned about the **appearance** of the number, and don't want to see it in scientific notation with the exponent.

This is default behaviour for just printing a `BigDecimal` and can't be overridden. But you *can* explicitly convert it to a String before printing.

This should do the trick:

```
val bd: BigDecimal = ...
println(bd.bigDecimal.toPlainString)
```

That said... Why not just use BigInt?

Comment: not appearance there is test case, on the test case the number is writing statically.I should make sure the testcase running thoroughly.

Comment: The OP gave correct results printed out without scientific notation, so I assumed that they also wanted the correct answer (which the `MathContext` fix will do).

Comment: @RexKerr There's a big enough language barrier that I wasn't sure either way - So I made sure to cover an interpretation that none of the existing answers had!